# Filter using specified column [tableutils.js]

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Im using `tableutils.js` plug in, inside this,the code to filter on first column is :

`$('#filter_searchMe_0').css('width','100px').detach().appendTo( "#outSide" );`

when im using for filtering the second column:

`$('#filter_searchMe_2').css('width','100px').detach().appendTo( "#outSide" );`

its not working,can anyone check if i missed something?

or can i declare this ,specifying also the element ID `('#filter_searchMe_2')`?

```
filter: {
         type: ['text']             
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bumbumpaw/md91vd5k/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

already solve using this :

```
filter: {
         type: ['noFilter','noFilter','text']             
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#filter_searchMe_2').css('width','100px').detach().appendTo( "#outSide" );
```

instead of above line use this

```
$('#filter_searchMe_1').css('width','100px').detach().appendTo( "#outSide" );
```